# Software that compares directories and backup/sync only modified files

Tags: windows-10, backup, incremental-backup

Is there a free software that will compare my D drive with my USB backup hardrive and copy/replace only the modified/newly created files to it? Windows 10 64 bits here.

Comment: Is the purpose to backup, or to sync each?

Comment: Try to rephrase your question.

Comment: It's to backup/sync to the USB HD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Robocopy** can do this.

It's already built into Windows 10 so all you need to do is invoke it from Command Prompt or use a batch file.

Let's assume:

D drive = data drive.

E drive = USB drive.

Use this syntax if you have **subfolders:**

`robocopy /e "d:\source data folder" "e:\USB backup folder" /r:1 /w:1`

Alternatively, use this syntax if you want to specify the **root** of your drives:

`robocopy /e d:\ e:\ /r:1 /w:1`

`/e` includes subdirectories and *E*mpty subdirectories. By default, only files are included and not any subdirectories.

`/r:1` *R*etries locked files 1 time.

`/w:1` *W*aits 1 second before reattempting locked files.

- If either the Size or the Last Modified dates differ between any given source and corresponding destination file then a destination file will be overwritten by the source file.
- Newly-created files will be included.
- Files deleted from the source will not be deleted from your USB drive. This behaviour can be changed by including the `/mir` (*MIR*ror) switch:

`robocopy /mir "d:\source data folder" "e:\USB backup folder" /r:1 /w:1`

- `/e` is redundant if `/mir` is used as the entire directory tree in the source will already be included.

Comment: thank you very much. Seems perfect.

Comment: Glad I could help! Have fun. Robocopy's a great little tool.